# I am using windows OS and mingw compiler and vscode as IDE How to add graphics library in c compiler after its set up already

Tags: c, graphics

[what is the exact error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmrMR.jpg)

I tried updating my softwares. I am expecting that I can code and generate graphics in c language. I have windows OS and visual studio code IDE and mingw compiler. How can I add graphics library in c compiler. I  want to generate graphics in c language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphics.h Not Working in VS Code version 1.15.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941496/graphics-h-not-working-in-vs-code-version-1-15-1)

Comment: not getting answer. Is it possible that IDE's do not support library in C ?

Comment: The [Borland Graphics Interface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Graphics_Interface) is approaching it’s 37 year anniversary. Unless you are required to use it for school I would highly recommend looking at a modern graphics API.